# count occurrences in python list and return values with the most occurrences along with the amount

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

So i have a list of strings like this:

```
mylist = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'abc']
```

and i want to have output like this:

```
foo exists twice
bar exists twice
abc exists once
```

I've tried converting the list to a dictionary with the string as the key and the value gets incremented for every occurrence in the list.
But I'm not able to sort the dictionary in a way that i can print the most strings with the most occurrences along with the word. 
I've also tried using a 2 dimensional arrays which didn't work either. Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `dict` or a `default_dict` and sort by values, but there's no need to reinvent the wheel. You need a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'abc'])
print(counter.most_common())
# [('foo', 2), ('bar', 2), ('abc', 1)]

for (word, occurences) in counter.most_common():
    print("%s appears %d times" % (word, occurences))
# foo appears 2 times
# bar appears 2 times
# abc appears 1 times
```